# Single object to Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, sql, datatables

I have a datatable `[CustomerEvent]` in database and the columns are: `Advices, Transports and Deleted`.

I am trying to put only one row to the datatable (maybe more in the future), but I can not figure out how to do this.

The following ajax request prints out this: `{Advices: 0, Transports: 1, Deleted: 0}`

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: "../json/stats.aspx?t=customer-stats" + "&n=" + caseId
}).done(function (data) {
   console.log(data)
```

So it sure returns the right information. However if I want to see this information in the datatable, I use the following ajax-request but it does not find any data:

```
$("#example").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "../json/stats.aspx?t=customer-stats" + "&n=" + caseId,
        "dataType" : "json",
        "dataSrc" : ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Advices" }
    ]
});
```

It says *"No data available in table"* and does not print out the `"0"` number. The ajax url does an SQL query to database, so maybe it has something to do with the `"data"`? Also, I am not sure if the return is an object or a json-string.

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Advices</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Advices</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you meant by next ajax request?

Comment: What I mean is, I think that the 2nd Ajax request is the one to be used in this situation. The first one is just a test to see if the sql request actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load datatable with data you get from separate AJAX call then, consider following:

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "../json/stats.aspx?t=customer-stats" + "&n=" + caseId
}).done(function (data) {
    //  onsole.log(data)
    //if there is only one data, eg: data = {Advices: 0, Transports: 1, Deleted: 0}
    table.row.add($("<tr><td>"+data.Advices+"</td></tr>")).draw();

    //  if multiple or array, eg: data = [{Advices: 0, Transports: 1, Deleted: 0}, {Advices: 1, Transports: 1, Deleted: 0}, {Advices: 2, Transports: 1, Deleted: 0}];
    //  disable comment to use it :)
    /*for (i in data) {
        table.row.add($("<tr><td>"+data[i].Advices+"</td></tr>")).draw();
    }*/
})
```

Else if you want datatable to pipeline the data from ajax then, do consider Server side processing in datatable.
Check the below reference:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

You have to provide ajax url to the datatable options

eg:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../json/stats.aspx?t=customer-stats" + "&n=" + caseId,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Advices" }
        ]
    } );
```

Your ajax page must return json like below:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 1,
  "recordsFiltered": 1,
  "data": [
    [
      "Advice1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Note: recordsTotal => total records in your table; recordsFiltered => total records you got after applying filters

Comment: Is there another way around it? Such as constructing the returning object from the first Ajax request to a string, and then adding it to a datatable variable? 

E.g: with the first Ajax request shown in this problem:

var table = $("#example").DataTable(); And: 


var stringtest = "<td>" + data.Advices + "</td></tr>". Then: 

table.row.add($(stringtest)).draw();

This solution returns the following warning:

DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Comment: You have add as row not as column. Try like below:

`var table = $("#example").DataTable();
var stringtest = "<tr><td>Advice1</td></tr>";
table.row.add($(stringtest)).draw();`

Comment: any up votes or my answer can be accepted as an answer to ur question? :) :P

Comment: Hello! I understand your answer but it only works if I reform the querys return to a json with "data:" attribute and such. I was looking for something simpler like your last comment. Maybe you should add it to your answer or do I upvote it anyway as the answer is in the comments, what do you think?

Comment: Updated the answer :)